Not able to decode base64 string in Substrate pallet
I am trying to decode a base64 string in pallet. Here is my code:
Cargo.toml
base64 = { version = "0.22.1", default-features = false, feature = ["alloc"] }

[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
  "base64/std",

Pallet
let input_base64 = "SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ==".to_owned();
let bytes =base64::prelude::BASE64_STANDARD.decode(input_base64).unwrap();

I am getting below error:
  error[E0599]: no method named `decode` found for struct `GeneralPurpose` in the current scope


1687 | ...                   let bytes =base64::prelude::BASE64_STANDARD.decode(input_base64).unwrap();
       |                                  ---------------------------------^^^^^^--------------
       |                                  |                                |
       |                                  |                                this is an associated function, not a method
       |                                  help: use associated function syntax instead: `GeneralPurpose::decode(input_base64)`
       |
       = note: found the following associated functions; to be used as methods, functions must have a `self` parameter
 


It works fine, when I run my tests inside pallet but gives error while running cargo build --release. Can somebody please help me to fix this?

If that answer resolved your issue, kindly "check mark" it. Otherwise the bot will ping this question multiple times.
If not, please add more detail to the question.

It's a typo mistake.
The alloc wasn't enabled.
- feature = ["alloc"]
+ features = ["alloc"]

